# jQuery draggable doesn't work after content is loaded via AJAX CAll

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to drag the card that In which I have filled data with Ng-Repeat, but the Jquery is not working on the dynamic data. ignore the rest of ajax calls they all are fine,just help in implementing the jquery on the div.card tag.
here is the code

```
<div class="card Bugg" id="hi" ng-repeat="bug in data">
    <p><b>Bug ID:</b></p>
    <p id="bugid"> {{bug.Bugid}}</p>
    <p><b>Bug Summary:</b></p>
    <p> {{bug.summary}}</p>
       <div id="bugButtons">
            <button id="buttonTask" type="button" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
                <div id="profileCircle"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card Bugg" id="hi">
    <p><b>Bug ID:</b></p> <p id="bugid">123</p>
    <p><b>Bug Summary:</b></p> 
    <p>OpenPGP should avoid weak crypto algorithms where possible (SHA-1, TRIPLEDES)</p>
    <div id="bugButtons">
      <button id="buttonTask" type="button" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
      <div id="profileCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //  $(".card").on( click,addListeners);
        function addListeners() {
          $(".card").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            start: function () {
              $(this).addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function () {
              $(this).removeClass("selected");
              if ($(this).parent().parent().prop('id') == "developerscard") {
                if ($(this).hasClass("Bugg")) {
                  $(this).parent().parent().append("hahahahah");
                  $(this).parent().parent().append($(this).find("#bugid").text());
                  $(this).addClass("Devo");
                  $(this).removeClass("Bugg");
                }
              }
              //for from dev to bug
              if ($(this).parent().parent().prop('id') == "bugcard") {
                if ($(this).hasClass("Devo")) {
                  $(this).parent().parent().append("bug big bug");
                  $(this).addClass("Bugg");
                  $(this).removeClass("Devo");

                }
              }
              //for bug old new location identification
            }
          });
          $(".column").droppable({
            accept: ".card",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
              ui.draggable
                .css("left", "0")
                .css("top", "0")
                .appendTo($(this).find(".cards"))
            }
          });
        }
        addListeners();
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour Your code does not offer a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Based on what you have presented, I suspect that the dynamically generated content has not been initialized as Draggable.